# Combined Fulltext Search API views filters that contains both all of these words filter and none of these words filter in Drupal

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-views

I have two exposed full text search API views filters that are used to filter the results returned from Apache Solr index. I want to give the user the ability to search text "containing all of these words" and "none of these words" and have used the respective views "Fulltext search" operators to achieve this. However, what is weird that whenever the none of these words filter is used, it increases the number of the returned search results instead of decreasing them and doesn't actually eliminate the results with the words mentioned.

Does this have to be done through search_api_query_alter?

[image: My views filter criteria]

[image: The filters that I am trying to achieve]